# Closing own question or deleting for too localized

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I realized after submitting a question today that my questions could not be answered due to a simple conceptual mistake on my part (there was no such mistake.)  Rather, solving my issue would require substantial debugging on a much larger amount of code.  I felt that, after learning this, the question was too localized and should be closed.

I believe I could still delete my question but am unsure which I should do.  I would regain 2 reputation by deleting it, but if that creates unwanted dead links, I would prefer to do the community appropriate action.

Is the correct course to vote to close (as I have) for too localized, or should I just delete my question?

The question: {deleted}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there aren't any answers and you feel that your question is unanswerable, go ahead and delete. The closing of unsalvageable posts is the path to deletion anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  The question has been deleted.